# Seekbar for mp3 from sd card

Tags: android, mp3, media-player, sd-card, seekbar

This code is to read a mp3 from raw folder,But I want to change my mp3 file to another file from sd card

**its new code, music played but seekbar does not work properly, when i toch it seekbar come back to frist position**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

SeekBar seek_bar;
Button play_button, pause_button;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
TextView text_shown;
Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getInit();
    seekUpdation();
}


public void getInit() {  
    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
    play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    pause_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
    text_shown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_shown);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    pause_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/music.mp3";
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    seek_bar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekUpdation();
    }
};

public void seekUpdation() {

    seek_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek_bar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek_bar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek_bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser){ 
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress); 
                seek_bar.setProgress(progress);
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.play_button:
        text_shown.setText("Playing...");
        mediaPlayer.start();
        break;
    case R.id.pause_button:
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        text_shown.setText("Paused...");
    }
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) { 
    if(fromUser){ 
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress); 
        seekBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move this line

```
seek_bar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

to `seekUpdation()` after

```
seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_file);
```

with:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/randomDirectory/yourFile.mp3";
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: **Mr. Daniel Zolnai i get this error by your answer** `04-08 22:30:10.260: E/MediaPlayer(17087): start called in state 0
04-08 22:30:10.260: E/MediaPlayer(17087): error (-38, 0)
4-08 22:30:10.340: E/MediaPlayer(17087): Error (-38,0)`

Comment: That's because you tried to start the MediaPlayer before it could load the datasource. See my edit in my answer how to solve it.

Comment: **thanks man, i change my code by new that come in my question,See my edit in it, but seekbar dont work Properly. when i toch it, seek bar come back to frist and music play from frist**

Comment: You should use mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress) in onStopTrackingTouch().

Comment: You probably use a variable which you didn't declare before. This is not in the scope of the current question though. If it still does not work, open another question with the other error.

Comment: Can you give me a source that play mp3 from SD card and sync with a seekbar?

Comment: Check these: http://jmsliu.com/2499/play-mp3-in-android-tutorial-android-mediaplayer-example.html http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-audio-files-in-android-with-a-seekbar-feature-and-mediaplayer-class/28243

Comment: in this links music play from res/raw, i want sd card surce with seekbar

Comment: my problem is in seekbar

Comment: `04-16 16:54:40.591: E/MediaPlayer(11635): Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
04-16 16:54:40.591: E/MediaPlayer(11635): error (-38, 0)
04-16 16:54:40.641: E/MediaPlayer(11635): Error (-38,0)
04-16 16:54:40.641: E/MediaPlayer(11635): Should have subtitle controller already set`